# Transform array into an object using an attribute as a reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need to convert an Array into an object, but I have no idea how to do this.

When I receive data from my API, it comes in the following structure:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    identifier: '0'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    identifier: '0,1,0'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    identifier: '0,1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    identifier: '0,0'
  }
]
```

After receiving the data I need to execute a method to convert them to the following structure based on the `identifier` attribute:

```
{
  id: 1,
  children: [
    {
      id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      children: [
        {
          id: 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea how I can get the desired result?

Comment: What did you try? Are the input lists guaranteed to correspond to a complete and valid output tree, and to be ordered such that children will always appear after all the parent nodes? Also could there be duplicate identifiers in the input? It's a more complicated problem if the input data might be invalid.

Comment: @HåkenLid I couldn't try much, I don't have a starting point to put the code into practice. The elements can be received in a random order. There is no chance of duplicated keys, the API will not allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` method to get an array from `identifier` string and then use `reduce` and `forEach` to build nested structure.

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"identifier":"0"},{"id":2,"identifier":"0,0"},{"id":3,"identifier":"0,1"},{"id":4,"identifier":"0,1,0"}]

const result = []

data.forEach(o => {
  o.identifier.split(',').reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
      if (!r[e]) r[e] = { children: [] }
      if (!a[i + 1]) r[e].id = o.id
      return r[e].children;
    }, result)
})

console.log(result)
```